# How to Inject AutoMapper as an instance using FreshMvvm and FreshIOC

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to inject `AutoMapper` into my `MainPageModel` for my Xamarin.Forms app but it crashes when loading the app.

I am setting it up like this, first init the config and then pass the implementing type to the DI container.

```
// Init automapper
AutoMapper.Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.AddProfile(new AppProfile()));

// Add automapper to DI
FreshMvvm.FreshIOC.Container.Register<IMapper, AutoMapper.Mapper>();

// Load page (results in crash)
var page = FreshPageModelResolver.ResolvePageModel<MainPageModel> ();
```

The error message I get is:

> TinyIoCResolutionException: Resolve failed: IConfigurationProvider

If I try to inject a regular `Service` with some `IService` interface instead, that works perfectly fine so it seems to be an issue with how FreshMvvm instanstiates the `AutoMapper` instance.

In most examples I have seen with injecting `AutoMapper` with other DI-containers, an instance is first created together with some configuration and then added to the container. Like this for an regular dot net core app:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Crate config instance
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
       cfg.AddProfile(new YourProfile());
    });

    // Create a mapper from config and add instance as singleton
    services.AddSingleton<IMapper>(sp => config.CreateMapper())
}
```

According to the docs (https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm#ioc-container-lifetime-registration-options) it seems FreshMvvm does not support adding instances though, and singletons are mapped like this:

```
FreshMvvm.FreshIOC.Container.Register<IService, MySingletonService>();
```

How can I inject `AutoMapper` with FreshMvvm? Do I need to create a DI mapping for the `IConfigurationProvider` provider as well? To which implementation if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is not obvious on this point. It is trivial once you understand how FreshIOC works. It accepts an instance as a parameter to the `Register` call.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddProfile(new AppProfile());
});

FreshMvvm.FreshIOC.Container.Register<IMapper>(config.CreateMapper());
```